# Best way to unit-test WCF REST/SOAP service while dynamically generating stubs

Tags: wcf, groovy, .net-4.0, ironpython, ironruby

I have a webservice written with WCF 4.0 that exposes REST and SOAP functions, and I want to set up my unit tests so that as I work on my web services I can quickly test by having the test framework start up the service, outside of IIS, and then do the tests.

I want it to be dynamically generated as I am not certain what the interface will look like, and it is easier to not worry about having to generate the stubs before I start the tests.

But, I couldn't get Groovy to work with my web service, so I am curious if Iron Python or Iron Ruby would work well for this, or is there another .NET language that may work well for this.

Comment: You don't really need stubs for the REST interface, right?

Comment: @Cem Catikkas - No, I don't need the stubs for REST, just SOAP, so Python, Groovy or Ruby would work for REST, as would javascript. Having one framework to test both SOAP and REST is the problem.

Comment: There are a lot of examples with Ruby, for example http://www.enonic.com/en/blog/Ruby+and+Vertical+Site:+Accessing+Data+With+SOAP.42838.cms explains how to create the stubs dynamically. However I don't think in unit tests you want this to run as a web service but instead directly invoke the server-side implementations.

Comment: @Cem Catikkas - I had tried creating the stubs dynamically in Ruby, but it seems that using a namespace causes problems, so it threw an error.  I just want to make certain the webservice works properly, as I had checked in code that was broken, and didn't realize it as all my unit tests had passed.

Answer (score 0):

[SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/) can take your WSDL and/or WADL and general your first order tests.  You can script up move complex usecase.  It is easy to use but powerful through the use of Groovy or Java.  It is without doubt the best test tool in this space.